# How do I solve issues with adding Tabbed Control with Expression Blend 3 for Silverlight App?

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, visual-studio-2008, expression-blend-3

I am using Microsoft Expression Blend 3 + SketchFlow Version 3.0.1927.0 for a Visual Studio 2008 Windows Embedded CE program.

I am trying to add a tabbed control and Expression Blend does not seem to be cooperating.  I have tried googling for a solution.  I found this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295163.aspx

This talks about SimpleTabControl and SimpleTabItem.  I did not find these controls in my list of available controls I can add.  This page says it is specific to WPF projects.  Could this be the problem and this particular page from MSDN.Microsoft.com is not applicable to my Silverlight project?

This web page says "The tab control is an items control that displays content in tabs".  I have the ability to add an items control:

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Embedded/itemscontrolpng_zpsq6zokxvq.png

The page also says "Typically, the child elements of a tab control are tab items, which are headered content controls, each of which can have a header element and a content element".  I did not find the ability to add a headered content control from the graphic list of available controls.

A google search also found this web page:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/tabcontrol-wpf

Trying this example producted this error:

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Embedded/tabcontroldoesnotexist_zpstq4euslm.png

It says "The name 'TabControl' does not exist in the namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007' "

Trying an exact copy of the example code produces an error that says that "Window" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

http://i67.photobucket.com/albums/h292/Athono/Embedded/windowdoesnotexist_zpsy4dn8rkm.png

I need to find an example or plan or solution for using a tab control for the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

Comment: Silverlight does have its own TabControl, that is indeed different to WPF (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol(v=vs.95).aspx 'other versions' if this isn't the SL one).

Comment: So Embedded CE is a bit different from full blown Silverlight, if I remember right from the last time I did embedded it's basically stripped down Silverlight 3, the tabcontrol you're wanting to use I believe is in the Silverlight Toolkit (what I had you download to use the theme I sent) which I'm not entirely sure works on embedded. However you could make a tabcontrol relatively easily but it will require some xaml knowledge.

Comment: Chris W, you are THE MAN.  The silverlight.codeplex.com installation produced 77 controls when there was much less before.  They include a number of tab controls.